# How to force Jaxb to use restriction types

Tags: jaxb, restriction, maven-jaxb2-plugin

for the following mapping

```
<xs:complexType name="ParentNode">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child" type="ChildNode"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ParentNodeRestriction">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="ParentNode">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="child" type="ChildNodeRestriction"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Jaxb generates the following classes (approximately)

```
public class ParentNode {
    protected ChildNode child;
}

public class ParentNodeRestriction
    extends ParentNode
{
}
 
public class ChildNode { 
}
 
public class ChildNodeRestriction
    extends ChildNode
{
}
```

Knowing that `ParentNode` is not used elsewhere than  `ParentNodeRestriction`, is it possible to force JAXB to generate the following class (hopefully without modifying the mapping):

```
public class ParentNodeRestriction
{
    protected ChildNodeRestriction child;
}
```

i.e. I need to have the most precise type for the `child` field.

ps : I am using `jaxb2-maven-plugin version 2.2` with maven

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using the xjb directive `<xjc:treatRestrictionLikeNewType/>` (*as indicated by his name*) generates classes for restrictions which do not inherit from the class corresponding to the parent mapping.
This solves the problem.

There seems to be a slight annoying consequence : elements with `maxOccurs="0"` are generated despite the `<xjc:simple/>` directive.

In fact, elements with `maxOccurs="0"` can be removed from the restriction definition.